# regex search works in Notepad++ but not in cygwin grep

Tags: regex, bash

I am doing a search in text file where I have to select part of a line after a successful match has happened.

Example
Problem:
I want to select the contents of a line after my search keyword `/abc/xyz` 
Sample file

`90:538566 :  Mike : Important : Comment : Deferred/Accepted : /abc/xyz/FileName1.hxx#2 (18)'
223:537558 :  Mike : Important : Comment : Deferred/Accepted : /abc/xyz/FileName2.hxx#2 (12)
266:537562 :  Mike : Important : Comment : Deferred/Accepted : /abc/xyz/FileName3.hxx#2 (23)
381:537576 :  Mike : Important : Comment : Deferred/Accepted : /abc/xyz/FileName3.cxx#2 (215 - 216)
394:537577 :  Mike : Important : Comment : Deferred/Accepted : /abc/xyz/FileName4.cxx#2 (231)`

Expected Output

`FileName1.hxx#2 (18)
FileName2.hxx#2 (12)
FileName3.hxx#2 (23)
FileName3.cxx#2 (215 - 216)
FileName4.cxx#2 (231)`

I am using Notepad++ to do this kind of search using Regular Expression Mode and searching for the following expression

`(?<=/abc/xyz/).*`

But I am not able to do the same kind of search using GNU grep that comes with the Cygwin distribution.

I tried the following search but it did not return any results.
`grep '(?<=/abc/xyz/).*' <filename.txt>`

I want to learn regex and figure out how this can be done with the help of grep? 
Can someone point me to a solution ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-Po` options for grep

`-P` Perl Regex
`-o` Only print match

```
grep -Po '(?<=/abc/xyz/).*' <filename.txt>

FileName1.hxx#2 (18)
FileName2.hxx#2 (12)
FileName3.hxx#2 (23)
FileName3.cxx#2 (215 - 216)
FileName4.cxx#2 (231)
```

You can also use `\K` instead of `?<=`

```
grep -Po '/abc/xyz/\K.*' <filename.txt>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does \K stand for? Can you suggest an approach with “basic,” (BRE) “extended” (ERE) regex ?

Comment: @k53sc This explains all the backslash escapes for perl regex http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html. And i don't think there is a way with BRE and grep to do that.

Comment: If you do not want to print `/abc/xyz`, then there is no way with BRE/ERE.